# datepicker values on post should not loose its behaviour

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-plugins, datepicker

- I am using 2 datepickers in which **return** should not be less than
  **departure**.
- On selecting of the datepicker, it is executing onSelect
  event functionality(pls check the datepicker script). But i want to make this while initial load
  without on select. Because issue is return datepicker is showing
  before date since i not select departure datepicker.This issue will happening when it is posted to another page, with same datepickers.

> eg: In first page i have selected 22-12-2014 and return 30-12-2014 ,
>   if i post these values to another page having same datepickers for
>   return i can able to select before 22-12-2014.

---

```
$("#departure").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: '+1d',
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        if (minDate) {
            minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate());
        }
        $("#return").datepicker("option", {minDate: minDate}, selectedDate);

    }

});

$("#return").datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    minDate: '+1d',
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    showButtonPanel: true,
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) { //alert($('#startPicker').val());
        var minDate = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        if (minDate) {
            minDate.setDate(minDate.getDate());
        }
        $("#departure").datepicker("option", {maxDate: minDate}, selectedDate);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to add the minDate again on the new page.
You could add something like:

```
<?php if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") { ?>
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#return").datepicker("option", {minDate: <?=$_POST['departureDate']; ?>}, selectedDate);
  });
<?php } ?>
```

Not tested but you get the idea.